# Opening One word document at a time

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I am creating an C# desktop application.
I want to open only one document at a time.
how can i know that already opened word document is closed by the user before i opens next.

The user has to close opened word document.

Any idea or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to open a document right now? I assume you have functioning code, but it opens an entire batch without waiting for the user to close one?

Comment: you need to search for all Word instances and check if there is any document opened. This could be done by checking `Documents.Count property`.

Comment: No @Yuck i am opening word document normally. By creating a object for both word application and document. put the entire code inside a method and passing the filepath as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how you application is interacting with Word documents? If your application is the only way for a user to open a word document, then once a document is open set a variable:

```
bDocOpen = true;
```

Once the document has been closed set it to false. Don't allow opening documents if bDocOpen equals true.

**EDIT**
You could launch the document and wait for the process to finish. This is not threaded, so your app will be unresponsive until the document is closed. I guess this behavior could be a mechanism to keep multiple documents from being opened. However leaving your app unresponsive is not a good practice, the user will think something is wrong.

```
bool bDocOpen = false;

private void btnOpenDoc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (!bDocOpen)
  {
    ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    pInfo.FileName = @"C:\temp\word.doc";
    Process p = Process.Start(pInfo);
    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    p.WaitForExit();

    //Will not get here till process exits
    MessageBox.Show("Document closed");
    bDocOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Application related documents are only opened by my application. But the user can open other document of his own. Is there any way to track the status of word document opened by my application.